# Use the polar form of a complex number to show that for any two numbers α and β

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

firstly, glad to finally sign up as a member here!

Okay so I have a complex number question here I'm very stumped with. It is as follows:

```
Use the polar form of a complex number to show that for any two
numbers α and β the following identities hold:

sin(α + β) = sin(α) cos(β) + cos(α) sin(β)  
cos(α + β) = cos(α) cos(β) − sin(α) sin(β)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$
w=e^{i\alpha}=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha\\
z=e^{i\beta}=\cos\beta+i\sin\beta
$$

Multiplying:
$$\begin{align}
wz=e^{i\alpha}\cdot e^{i\beta}&=(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)(\cos\beta+i\sin\beta)\\
e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}&=(\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta)+i(\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta)\\
\text{Using De Moivre's theorem,}\hspace{2cm}\\
\cos(\alpha+\beta)+i\sin(\alpha+\beta)&=(\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta)+i(\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta)\\
\text{Equating real and imaginary parts}\hspace{1cm}\\
\cos(\alpha+\beta)&=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
\sin(\alpha+\beta)&=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! Kinda wish I could give you both a tick since Thomas helped greatly also. Had no issues with this method

Comment: Thanks!  Well, you could also give him an upvote. Glad to know it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Try representing $z_{1} = e^{i\alpha}$ and $z_{2} = e^{i\beta}$, and remember Euler's formula: $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$.

Then remember that the real and imaginary parts are independent.